# Partial/Missing values date field MS access

Tags: ms-access-2010

I am getting an import error when importing data with missing date values. Some older date values don't have month or day but do have a year value. Can you insert a place holder for the missing "day" value so that Access will recognize it as a date?

Comment: which method/technology are you using to import data? what is the error (error code, message)?

Answer (score 0):

In a query you can use:

```
OldDate: DateSerial([FieldWithYear],1,1)
```